# How to clear mouse click buffer

Tags: delphi, mouse

We may use the following code to clear keyboard buffer:

```
while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE or PM_NOYIELD) do;
```

But how may I clear mouse click buffer?

Comment: I do not understand how one could upvote an answer and do not upvote a question? If an answer was helpful then the question was definitely too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it:

```
while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, WM_MOUSEFIRST, WM_MOUSELAST, PM_REMOVE or PM_NOYIELD) do;
```

Comment: s/KEY/MOUSE/ - who would have thought **that**? :-)

Comment: @Ulrich: +1 for that hilarious comment :D