# How to discard mouse click in TDbGrid.OnColumnMoved

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

In a `TDbGrid.OnColumnMoved` event handler, I adjust some column headings colors.

I also use the grid's `OnTitleClicked` event to pop-up a (sort column) menu.

Unfortunately, after the user drags a column and `OnColumnMoved` is finished, the VCL calls `OnTitleClicked`.  This means my sort-order pop-up appears after column dragging.

Is there a way in `OnColumnMoved` I can clear the mouse event queue so that `OnTitleClicked` doesn't get called?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400332/how-to-clear-mouse-click-buffer) has this code, but I don't have a `Msg` in `OnTitleClicked`.

```
while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, WM_MOUSEFIRST, WM_MOUSELAST, 
  PM_REMOVE or PM_NOYIELD) do;
```

(If there's no way to do this, it's not big deal. I can set a flag in `OnColumnMoved` so that `OnTitleClick` ignores the next call to it.)

Comment: You do know you can declare your own `Msg: tagMsg` (or `TMsg') variable and use it in the call to `PeekMessage`? Don't think that's the answer here, but just FYI...

Comment: Hmmmm - not every OnColumnMoved event also triggers an OnTitleClick event for me (Delphi 10.1), so the flag is unreliable. I could use a timer, so if the OnTitleClick occurs within (say) 0.25 seconds of OnColumnMoved, it gets ignored. But that's like using a sledgehammer to kill a flea. Any further thoughts on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in comments to the question, you would supply the 'Msg' for `PeekMessage` yourself (`var Msg: TMsg`). But discarding the message that triggers `OnTitleClick`is not possible because it is the same message that fires both events. VCL carries out column moving in response to a `WM_LBUTTONUP` message if a column has been dragged. Later during the handling of the same message `OnTitleClick` is called.

IOW, while you can remove messages from the message queue with `PeekMessage`, the message that triggers `OnTitleClick` is already dispatched since we are in an `OnColumnMoved` handler.

Easiest approach looks like setting the flag as you've told.