# How to detect if column was moved?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tdbgrid

I'm sorting a `TDBGrid` using it's `OnTitleClick` event, but I don't want to sort the grid when the user just arranges his columns.

Is it possible to detect if the column was moved / is moving when the `OnTitleClick` event fires?

`OnStartDrag` is not fired, because the drag and drop seems to be internal to the grid component.

The only thing I can think of right now is to set a flag when `OnColumnMoved` is fired and ignore the next execution of the `OnTitleClick` event.

Is this a good idea or is there a better way?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498746/how-to-discard-mouse-click-in-tdbgrid-oncolumnmoved

Comment: Your suggested approach sounds fine. For extra peace of mind you can timestamp the flag you set in OnColumnMoved so you only ignore the event if it's not too long ago.